# How to use keras to fine-tune inception v3 to do multi-class classification?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras

I want to use Keras to do two classes image classify using Cat vs. Dog dataset from Kaggle.com.
But I have some problem with param "class_mode" as below code.
if I use "binary" mode, accuracy is about 95%, but if I use "categorical" accuracy is abnormally low, only above 50%.

binary mode means only one output in last layer and use sigmoid activation to classify. sample's label is only one integer.

categorical means two output in last layer and use softmax activation to classify.  sample's label is one hot format, eg.(1,0), (0,1).

I think these two ways should have the similar result. Anyone knows the reason for the difference? Thanks very much!

```python
import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras import __version__
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

set some params here

```python
IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 299, 299 #fixed size for InceptionV3
NB_EPOCHS = 1
BAT_SIZE = 32
FC_SIZE = 1024
NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE = 172
loss_mode = "binary_crossentropy"

def get_nb_files(directory):
  """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    return 0
  cnt = 0
  for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
      cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
  return cnt
```

transfer_learn, keep the weights in inception v3

```python
def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
  """Freeze all layers and compile the model"""
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=loss_mode, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Add last layer to do two classes classification.

```python
def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top
    nb_classes: # of classes
  Returns:
    new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) #new FC layer, random init
  if args.class_mode == "binary":
    predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x) #new softmax layer
  else:
    predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x) #new softmax layer
  model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
  return model
```

Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top layers,
and fine tune weights.

```python
def setup_to_finetune(model):
  """Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top layers.
  note: NB_IV3_LAYERS corresponds to the top 2 inception blocks in the inceptionv3 arch
  Args:
    model: keras model
  """
  for layer in model.layers[:NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE]:
     layer.trainable = False
  for layer in model.layers[NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE:]:
     layer.trainable = True
  model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=loss_mode, metrics=['accuracy'])
  #model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


def train(args):
  """Use transfer learning and fine-tuning to train a network on a new dataset"""
  nb_train_samples = get_nb_files(args.train_dir)
  nb_classes = len(glob.glob(args.train_dir + "/*"))
  nb_val_samples = get_nb_files(args.val_dir)
  nb_epoch = int(args.nb_epoch)
  batch_size = int(args.batch_size)
  print("nb_classes:{}".format(nb_classes))
```

data prepare

```python
  train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.train_dir,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    #class_mode='binary'
    class_mode=args.class_mode
  )

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    args.val_dir,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    #class_mode='binary'
    class_mode=args.class_mode
  )
```

setup model

```python
  base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False) #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
  model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)
```

transfer learning

```python
  setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)

  #model.summary()

  history_tl = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//BAT_SIZE,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_val_samples//BAT_SIZE)
```

fine-tuning

```python
  setup_to_finetune(model)

  history_ft = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//BAT_SIZE,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_val_samples//BAT_SIZE)

  model.save(args.output_model_file)

  if args.plot:
    plot_training(history_ft)


def plot_training(history):
  acc = history.history['acc']
  val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
  loss = history.history['loss']
  val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
  epochs = range(len(acc))

  plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r')
  plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')

  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r.')
  plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r-')
  plt.title('Training and validation loss')
  plt.show()
```

main func

```python
if __name__=="__main__":
  a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  a.add_argument("--train_dir", default="train2")
  a.add_argument("--val_dir", default="test2")
  a.add_argument("--nb_epoch", default=NB_EPOCHS)
  a.add_argument("--batch_size", default=BAT_SIZE)
  a.add_argument("--output_model_file", default="inceptionv3-ft.model")
  a.add_argument("--plot", action="store_true")
  a.add_argument("--class_mode", default="binary")


  args = a.parse_args()
  if args.train_dir is None or args.val_dir is None:
    a.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

  if args.class_mode != "binary" and args.class_mode != "categorical":
    print("set class_mode as 'binary' or 'categorical'")

  if args.class_mode == "categorical":
    loss_mode = "categorical_crossentropy"

  #set class_mode
  print("class_mode:{}, loss_mode:{}".format(args.class_mode, loss_mode))

  if (not os.path.exists(args.train_dir)) or (not os.path.exists(args.val_dir)):
    print("directories do not exist")
    sys.exit(1)

  train(args)
```

Comment: Are you sure `nb_classes` is correctly set to 2? It's difficult to say from your `train()` function...

Comment: Yes. I can check it with "print("nb_classes:{}".format(nb_classes))"

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I use SDG or Adam optimizer, the accuracy can go up normally. So is there something wrong using RMSprop optimizer with default learning rate=0.001?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on several tasks when the learning rate was too high. Try something like 0.0001 or even less.

According to the Keras Documentation, the default rate ist 0.001:

```
keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
```

See https://keras.io/optimizers/#rmsprop